# pseudo-classes em CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um módulo que irá mostrar informações. essas informações deverão ser exibidas como div's expandíveis, o que eu criei utilizando apenas CSS como está [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/leandroluk/p07tpn2v/):

```
.news .itens {
    overflow: auto;
    margin-right: -20px;
    height: 292px;
    float: left;
    width: 290px;
    font-size: 65%;
}

.news .itens a {
    float: left;
    width: 258px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    text-align: right;
    height: auto;
    background:rgba(168, 202, 106,0.3);
    line-height: 25px;
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(168, 202, 106);
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.news .itens p {
    display:none;
    float: left;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    width: 248px;
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.news .itens a:focus p{
    display:block;
}

.news .itens a:first-child p{
    display:block;
}

.news .itens a:first-child + .news .itens a:focus p{
    display:none;
}
```

Meu problema é que preciso fazer com que o primeiro elemento existente na div `a:first-child` se feche assim que for clicado em outro elemento existente, e que quando nenhum elemento estiver `focus`, que ele fique aberto como está no CSS.

Como poderia ser feito isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja este exemplo:

1º HTML ->

```
<div id="acordeon">
   <a href="#primeira">Primeira</a>        
   <div id="primeira">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
   </div>
   <a href="#segunda">Segunda</a>        
   <div id="segunda">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
   </div>
   <a href="#terceira">terceira</a>        
   <div id="terceira">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
   </div>
```

2º CSS ->

```
#acordeon div {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 600ms;
    background: #999;
}
 #acordeon div: target {
    height: 110px;
}
```

Comment: Essa regra de transição que você utilizou só funcionará no em navegadores *webkit*. Não esqueça do suporte a outros navegadores, um simples `transition: height 600ms;` resolve.

Comment: Editado ---------------------